# DX11 texture to DX12 conversion

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, directx, directx-11, directx-12

I am looking for a resource to fetch a DX12 texture from a window.   It looks like there is a way to get DX11 via WinRT apis, however I am seeing no methods to up-convert DX11 texture to DX12.  I've looked in the DX11 and 12 docs best I could and cannot find a conversion method.  An API I want to use is DX12 only and I need the texture to be in DX12 to be compatible.

Unless there is a newer RT method to get DX12 (preferred solution as its direct).. I couldn't find any documented ones there either.

Comment: If you have a DirectX 11 resource, you can use interop to access it from DirectX 12. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/direct3d12/direct3d-12-with-direct3d-11--direct-2d-and-gdi).

Comment: I found that when you create an 11 on 12 device using an api there, you can then call https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11on12/nf-d3d11on12-id3d11on12device2-unwrapunderlyingresource ... I will answer question once I get a 12 instance going and get the conversion successful.